# MemberExpression, build Expression.Property from class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, linq-expressions

Below expression compares property NAME with the value PETER.

```
            ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(pe, "name");
            ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant("Peter");
            exp = Expression.Equal(member, value);
```

What if the property is a class:

```
            public class Address
            {
                public string Name {get; set;}
            }
```

Then the expression would look something similar to this:

```
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(pe, "Address.Name");
            ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant("Peter");
            exp = Expression.Equal(member, value);
```

This would fail because the member type doesn't match the value type.

So, the question is: How to build an Expression that would work using the above class sample ??

I use this expression in a NHibernate.Linq query:

```
        var q = from f in data //of type IQueryable<T>
            select f;
        if (filter != null) //filter of type Expression<Func<T, bool>>
            q = q.Where(filter);
        etc....
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE by Peter**:

Based on the code from xanatos (next post) I have created the following test to understand how it works. Its not very different from what xanatos do, but at first I could not get it to work, so I decided to write it allover in one simple test, and that did it. With thanks to xanatos:

```
    [Test]
    public void FilterWithDeepProperties()
    {
        //Arrange
        IGenericGridRepository repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IGenericGridRepository>();

        FilterDescriptor filter = new FilterDescriptor("AgreementId.Name", FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, "a name");
        string[] properties = filter.Member.Split('.');
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SampleDomain), "x");

        //Act
        Expression lastMember = pe;
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(lastMember, properties[i]);
            lastMember = member;
        }
        ConstantExpression valueExpression = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
        Expression equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(lastMember, valueExpression);
        Expression<Func<SampleDomain, bool>> where = Expression.Lambda<Func<SampleDomain, bool>>(equalityExpression, pe);
        var result = repository.GetObjects<SampleDomain>(filter: where);

        //Assert
        result.Count().Should().BeGreaterThan(0, "because there are many schedule items equals to " + filter.Value);
    }
```

Comment: You are looking from the wrong point of view. `typeof(T)` is already a type (a class for example), so in your example `typeof(T)` is `typeof(Address)`... unless there is an over-object `Person` that has an `Address ` that has a `string Name`...

Comment: I get it, but it is as you end up with (the over-object), like the following sample: select t.*, a.name from SomeTable t inner join AddressTable a on a.Id = t.AddressTableId where a.name = 'Peter'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> GetEquality<TSource>(object value, params string[] properties)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "source");

    Expression lastMember = pe;

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(lastMember, properties[i]);
        lastMember = member;
    }

    Expression valueExpression = Expression.Constant(value);
    Expression equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(lastMember, valueExpression);
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(equalityExpression, pe);
    return lambda;
}
```

Use it like:

```
Expression exp = GetEquality<Person>("Foo", "Address", "Name");
```

Where `Foo` is your `Peter` (so the value that must be compared), while `Address` and `Name` are the names of the "chain" of properties. For example I'm using

```
public class Person
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So the expression generated is

```
source.Address.Name == "Foo"
```

If you want to use something like `Address.Name`, you can use the method like

```
Expression exp = GetEquality<Person>("Foo", "Address.Name".Split('.'));
```

Comment: This does looks promising - I gotta try it to fully understand it :-) What type would TSource be (my parent class?) ??

Comment: @PeterLarsen'CPH' What you called `T` in `typeof(T)`. I called it `TSource` because in version 0.1 of the code there were a `TSource` and a `TTarget` for the value. Then `TTarget` was removed :)

Comment: OK, let me try it. Thanks so far :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think there might be an error somewhere in the code since I could not get it to work at first ;-), but it's not really important since your code set me off in the right direction :-)